# How to avoid "Task size too large"?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My issue is that I'm getting task size too large warnings while using Spark SQL to denormalize tables into larger tables.

Before people point to other answers saying to use broadcast or avoid closing on the entire class; let me say that I've read those and am still confused specifically when using Spark SQL.

I have task sizes going up to 10 times the recommended size when using Spark SQL.

**Here's the situation:**

- I have 10+ tables/data-frames to join into an uber-table.
- I created a single scala object and in the body populated those 10 tables from their CSVs.
- I import the members of that object (just the tables) in other objects where the calculation to form he uber-tables is.
- When the Spark-SQL joins between those 10 tables run to, say, write the result table to a parquet file, I get the task size warnings.

**Extra Information:**

- I've tried moving the source tables into different classes and embedding them in functions and the task sizes did not change.
- I'm unsure how broadcast could help with this as the source data is read straight into data frames using Spark-CSV, and thus should already be distributed.

Comment: Can you include the warnings in the question? Can you show the code that leads to the warnings?

Answer (score -1):

In Spark, you can choose the [caching (persistence) level](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence) to unload some large in-memory objects to disk, and use `unpersist()` to choose which already-cached results to throw away.

Comment: Please flesh out your answer a little more, such as explaining how choosing a caching level avoids large memory usage and an example of how `unpersist()` can be used to free up memory.